# how does SOQL compare IDs

Tags: soql, workbench, id-comparison

This is more of a conceptual question. I was initially querying attachments related to a specific object like this -

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Description, BodyLength,IsDeleted,IsPrivate,CreatedById,CreatedDate FROM Attachment where 
 ParentId IN (Select Id from my_custom_object__c)
```

but it kept timing out in workbench. So someone gave me wonderful idea to write query like this

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Description, BodyLength,IsDeleted,IsPrivate,CreatedById,CreatedDate FROM Attachment where  (ParentId > ‘a1e000000000000000’) AND (ParentId <‘a1ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzz’)
```

where **a1e** is the object prefix of my_custom_object__c.

So we kind of define a custom range a1e000000000000000 to a1ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, where all records of my_custom_object__c are bound to be in (as in their IDs will be in this range)

This works well. But then i started to think, which is higher "max range" - a1ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzz or a1eZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

I tested with one particular Id (just picked up a random contact record), and wrote following code in dev console -

```
//Id of a contact record
Id tempId = '0032900000EbFYyAAN';
//change capital E to small e and compare
if(tempId > '0032900000ebFYyAAN'){System.debug('@@@ capital is greater');}
if(tempId < '0032900000ebFYyAAN'){System.debug('@@@ small is greater');}
if(tempId == '0032900000ebFYyAAN'){System.debug('@@@ same');}
```

And it printed ***@@@ small is greater***

So does that mean, as far as comparison of IDs go, small letters are always evaluated to be bigger than capital letters? From this one test, can i assume that it is indeed the case all the time? How does salesforce internally compare two IDs?

EDIT - After reading some comments, I guess when i write **where  (ParentId > ‘a1e000000000000000’) AND (ParentId <‘a1ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzz’)** , i am comparing ID with string. But the question stays the same - how does it work? Am i covering entire range of records when i write this? or do i need to change it to capital Z. And to clarify, queries are being run via workbench, not inside apex code

Comment: While ids are unique they are not guaranteed to be in chronological order. Just something to keep in mine.

Comment: @Eric then again, they do recommend to use id forward paging in LDS docos..

Comment: I guess I should say sequentially rather than chronological. Depending on you rage the may not matter

Comment: did you try to compare Id with Id (because now it seems they Id with String is compared)?

Comment: You've used the 18 character ID form which exists to make the ID case insensitive. What happens if you do this with the 15 character form? (And make sure you do compare ID to ID, not ID to String as @kurunve mentioned)

Comment: @Eric, I'd say order of ID is irrelevant here since the query is trying to cover the entire ID range with a given prefix. Something else worth considering - don't hard-code the ID prefix, get this from the object describe (DescribeSObjectResult.keyPrefix). And talking about that, note the following caveat in the docs: "Note that a key prefix can sometimes be shared by multiple objects so it does not always uniquely identify an object".

Comment: @kur I guess the real question is when i write     where  (ParentId > ‘a1e000000000000000’) AND (ParentId <‘a1ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzz’)      how is that comparison done? I guess this is ID being compared to string. But whats the internal mechanism? I just want to make sure ID of ALL the records fall in that range

Comment: That's in the context of SOQL so may include some implicit conversion. Who knows?

Comment: @PhilW I need to run queries via workbench, so i dont have the option to use object describe

Comment: OK, not obvious from your question but fair enough. Just because you were running with workbench didn't imply the final solution is workbench :)

Comment: @PhilW Yeah i realized that. I just edited title of the post (removed "apex" from it) and added the edit at the end

Comment: To be on the save side, I'd just filter for (ParentId < ‘a1f000000000000000’).

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about ASCII? [Here](http://www.asciitable.com/) is a reference for it. From the ASCII table, you can see that 'E' is 69 and 'e' is 107. When you compare two string, they will be transferred at first to ASCII value and then compare them. That's why did you get the result of 'small is greater'.